# Dibujar una "X" y "✔" en un canvas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, canvas

Realice un canvas en el cual ya puedo dibujar un punto pero ahora necesito dibujar los simbolos "X" y "✔" y que solo se pueda dibujar una vez cada simbolo.

Aquí dejo mi codigo

```js
$("#canvas").click(function(e) {
  getPosition(e);
});

var pointSize = 3;

function getPosition(event) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = event.clientX - rect.left;
  var y = event.clientY - rect.top;
  drawCoordinates(x, y);
}

function drawCoordinates(x, y) {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ff2626"; // Red color
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, pointSize, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="300" style="cursor:crosshair;background:url(https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5502/9646969759_218c6781ef.jpg);background-size: 200px 300px;"></canvas>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme.
Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa `fillText()` y símbolos unicode:

```js
$("#canvas").click(function(e) { 
   var rect = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect()
   var x = e.clientX - rect.left
   var y = e.clientY - rect.top
   var ctx = e.currentTarget.getContext("2d")
   ctx.fillStyle = "#ff2626"
   ctx.fillText('\u2713', x, y) // El otro símbolo es '\u2717'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="300" style="cursor:crosshair;background:url(https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5502/9646969759_218c6781ef.jpg);background-size: 200px 300px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! me funciono bien. Saludos.